# Помощь с массивом

Tags: java

Есть 2 массива, в каждом из которых n элементов.  В первом значение некой переменной w, во втором значение функции, зависящей от этой переменной. Границы массива с переменной w, w1 и w2, вводятся программистом с клавиатуры. Каждое последующее значение увеличивается на переменную h, которая равна `h = (w2-w1)/(n-1);`

Вопрос: как вывести эти массивы, чтобы выполнялись условия?

P.S. Пробовал

```
for(;w1<w2; w1+=h)
System.out.println(w);
```

выводит дичь какую-то

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Kurs 
{
  static int n; 
  static double w1, w2; 
  static double [] w,z,a; 
  static double h = (w2-w1)/(n-1); 

  static void calc() 
  { 
    double c1=50e-9;
    double c2=35e-9; 
    double l1=1.4e-3; 
    double l2=2e-3; 
    double x; 
    double y; 
    w[0]=w1; 
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
      w[i]=w[i-1]+h;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      x=1-(w[i]*w[i]*l1*c1); 
      y=1-w[i]*w[i]*l2*c2; 
      z[i]=Math.sqrt(Math.abs(((2*l1*xyy)-(w[i]*w[i]*l1*l1*c2*y)‌​)/(xxc2)));
      a[i]= 1-((w[i]*w[i]*l1*c1)/x*y); 
    }
  } 

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    n=s.nextInt();
    w1=s.nextDouble();
    w2=s.nextDouble();
    w=new double[n];
    z=new double[n];
    a=new double[n];
    calc();
    for(;w1<w2; w1+=h) 
      System.out.println(w1);
    for(;w1<w2; w1+=h) 
      System.out.println(z); 
    for(;w1<w2; w1+=h) 
      System.out.println(a); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы пишете: "вводятся программистом с клавиатуры". А кто в задаче является программистом?

Comment: @oxdb а можно как-то по теме отвечать и не придираться к словам?

Comment: @Pahandriy Можно. Дополните пожалуйста ваш вопрос кодом.

Comment: извиняюсь что как-то некрасиво, первый раз пишу сюда

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/648940/edit) нажмите и вставте код в вопрос. Выделите код и [Ctrl-K]. Уже лучше. Коменарии с кодом можете удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, так гораздо лучше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  w[i] = w1 + h * i;
  System.out.println(w[i]);
}
```

Вы же понимаете, конечно, что вычисление

```
h = (w2 - w1) / (n - 1);
```

надо выполнять после

```
n = s.nextInt();
w1 = s.nextDouble();
w2 = s.nextDouble();
```

а не там, где декларируется `h`, и где никакие `n`, `w1` и `w2` еще неизвестны.

Comment: @Pahandriy Это Вы просто неправильно мой код к себе скопировали :).

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо большое)
А почему так получается с h, в чем разница между ее инициализацией в теле класса и в мейне?

Comment: @Pahandriy Посмотрите, я дописал в ответе. Так понятнее?

Comment: да, разобрался
Спасибо:)